# Prove that the direct sum $\coprod_p \mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$ is not a direct summand of the product $\prod_p \mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that the direct sum $\coprod_p \mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$ over all prime integers $p$ is not a direct summand of the product $\prod_p \mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$.

For finite products, I know that direct sums and products are essentially the same. However, I'm having trouble visualizing their differences even in the infinite case.

Comment: *Hint:* As abelian groups, if $K$ is a direct summand of $M$, then the identity map $K \to K$ should factor through the inclusion $K \hookrightarrow M$. In other words, the inclusion should have a left inverse. Why doesn't this work here?

Comment: Are you interestend in proving that there isn't a split exact sequence $$0\to \coprod_p \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\stackrel f\longrightarrow\prod_p \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\stackrel g\longrightarrow H\to 0,$$ or are you interested in proving the special case that there isn't one such that the image of $f$ is $V:=\{x\in\prod_p\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\,:\, \lvert\{p\ :\ x_p\ne 0\}\rvert<\aleph_0\}$ ?

Comment: @SammyBlack How do you get that the map should factor through the inclusion $K \to M$. For example, if $K = M \oplus M$ what would the inclusion map $K \to M$ be?